# Native code Android Studio 1.5 and Experimental plugin 0.4, including .so files

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-ndk, android-studio-import

My setup:
- Android Studio 1.5
- Android NDK-r10e
- Experimental Plugin 0.4.0

I tried following so many tutorials online on compiling native codes in Android Studio, but I'm stuck at one problem: including .so files.

I need to use GMP & OpenSSL in my code. I tried adding `#include <gmp.h>` to the sample hello-jni code supplied from [github](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk) to test if my C code can read the .so files, but it returned error:

> gmp.h: No such file or directory

This is my folder structure (I tried compiling against x86 first)

[image: folder structure]

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep `.so` files and header files `.h` separately. Under the `jniLibs` folder only `.so` files are needed. Keep header file under `jni/headers` folder separately and access them from that folder. Also you don't need to include `.a` files under `jniLibs` folder.

add header file path under `jni source dir` in gradle build file. Access header file like `#include "gmp.h"` with `double quotes` instead of `angle brackets` to search in local user paths.

Comment: thanks. already followed your advised. but the error didn't resolve.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the include path(s) in **build.gradle** file, see more at http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental#TOC-Ndk-Integration

```
model {
    android.ndk {
        moduleName = "hello-jni"
        def jniLibs = file("app/src/main/jniLibs/x86").getAbsolutePath()
        println(file("app/src/main/jniLibs/x86/gmp.h").exists())
        CFlags.add("-I$jniLibs".toString())
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried your suggestion, but results in similar error. have you ever tried this? which version of experimental plugin did you use?

Comment: tried your updated code.. still same error occur.. T_T

Comment: to debug this, you add some **println()**